# php кавычки внутри кавычек допустимы?

Tags: php

Есть вот такой код. И он работает.

```
$x = array( "xxx" );
print( "={$x["0"]}=" );
```

Выводит без всяких ошибок и варнингов

```
=xxx=
```

В документации ничего про это не нашел. Тыкните если знаете где читать.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing   в частности "сложный"

Comment: Это интерполяция, но в PHP работающая через одно место.

Comment: А можно полагаться на эту интерполяцию? Узнать когда она появилась и сколько проработает?